# C++ expected ')' before parameter name

Tags: c++

I'm very new to C++. I'm trying to make a basic class called Book and I'm getting an error in my `.cpp` file:

> error: expected ')' before 'theAuthor'

and then 'author', 'title', and 'pages' all say:

> unable to resolve identifier

I've looked at a number of examples online and I can't see anything I've done wrong.

`Book.h`:

```
#include <string>
using namespace std;

#ifndef BOOK_H
#define BOOK_H

class Book{
public:
    string author;
    string title;
    int pages;

    Book(string theAuthor,string theTitle,int thePages);
};
#endif  /* BOOK_H */
```

`Book.cpp`:

```
#include "Book.h"
#include <string>
using namespace std;

Book(string theAuthor,string theTitle,int thePages){
    author = theAuthor;
    title=theTitle;
    pages=thePages;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change:

```
Book(string theAuthor,string theTitle,int thePages){
    author = theAuthor;
    title=theTitle;
    pages=thePages;
}
```

to:

```
Book::Book(string theAuthor,string theTitle,int thePages){
    author = theAuthor;
    title=theTitle;
    pages=thePages;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That was in the example I read but not until the very end

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare it like so:

```
Book::Book(string theAuthor,string theTitle,int thePages){
```

This way, the compiler knows that you are trying to implement the Constructor (that's what the second "Book(...)" is for) of the class "Book" (that's what "Book::" means)

Comment: This is not the declaration, this is the definition, the declaration was in the header file.

Answer (score 1):

You've declared the constructor of `Book` inside your class, but you've placed the definition outside. That definition isn't of a free function, so you must name both the class and the method of the class which you're defining. For a constructor, those names are identical. So: `Book::Book`.

A destructor definition outside your class would be `Book::~Book` but the default destructor usually is OK.